# How to avoid shutdown tomcat in every time do modification

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDE for Java EE Applications, when i do any modification in any resource like sevlet or jsp ,and do requests to this resources i don't see the modification ,i must shutdown my application server 
and start it to see my modification , iam using tomcat v9 , when i used eclipse or netbeans in last with the same version of tomcat ,iam not faced this problem ,
It seems that the problem is in IntelliJ. i'd like to avoid the application server shutdown every time i do a modification .
any one can help

Comment: Are you running Tomcat in "debug mode"?

Comment: No , i get error when i run on debugger

Comment: have you tried this? https://www.mkyong.com/intellij/intellij-idea-auto-reload-a-web-application-hot-deploy/

Comment: I tried all these solutions but did not work

Comment: I now tried  these solutions  again ,its work fine but must i recompile the resource before run in debug mode ,thanks so much

Comment: Check out JRebel (paid application) or open source alternative Hotswap Agent.